# Kali Linux 19 boot menu beep

Tags: boot, kali-linux

I am running a Kali Linux 19 Live USB and there is a high pitched beep whenever I boot Kali from my USB drive.

I have been through what has been written on the web but I can't find a menu.cfg file to remove the BEL or G signs.

Anyone else having the same issue? Could anyone please assist? The aim is to remove this beep sound on startup (kali boot menu) and when I switch users...

Cheers, James

Comment: I guess your flashing method does not allow you to edit the flashed drive, It happend, for example Balena Etcher does this way as well. Have not analyzed the reasons but  Rufus does the job.

Answer (score 0):

It is still an annoying feature in version 2020.3.
However, it is easily fixable.

Follow the steps:

1. Flash the Kali linux ISO with [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/), it let's you edit the files after flashing the pendrive. If it asks for mode in the popup just go with recommended settings.
2. After it finished flashing, open the newly created drive in file
   explorer and search for **isolinux/menu.cfg**. Open it with
   Notepad++. Different editors will show differently what we search for!
3. Somewhere around the 4th row it contains this: "menu title Boot
   menu", and a sign at the end of this line in Notepad++ you will see something like "**BEL**" in. That is the character responsible for the beeping.
   Regular Notepad under windows wil display "[]", under linux might look like "^G".
4. Delete the above mentioned sign, the row should contain only the "menu title Boot menu" words.
5. Save it
6. Restart the machine and test it!

That's all! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

/boot/grub/config.cfg

```
# Comment these two lines out to disable the beep on boot
insmod play
play 960 440 1 0 4 440 1
```